# ExactTarget Web Collect via AJAX POST

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm having some trouble trying to understand how to set up an AJAX POST to ET's Web Collect. Has anyone used this before?

I'm building a simple subscribe box that will disappear when the user has subscribed, I only want to be able to send the bare minimum necessary data to ET (email address, MID, LID) if possible.

Is it absolutely necessary to use the Error, Thank you, and Unsubscribe pages? I am building a form that disappears after the user has subscribed and don't want any type of redirect.

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Are you building this in an ET landing page/microsite or on a page outside of the platform?

Comment: This will be on a completely external page.

Answer (score 1):

My company was migrating from Mailchimp to Marketing Cloud.

As we had a form that only displayed feedback text instead of a redirect through use of AJAX we wanted to keep the concept with Exact Target too.

Submitting through the jQuery $.ajax function, the *success* callback was not returning data, however the *error* callback was returning a 200 OK and a statusText of "Success". Additionally after checking the DB in Exact Target the user information was being entered correctly.

Try and check the error data returned and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would try: for your redirects, I would use the SAME url as the current page for all three, but I would put something in the query string that lets you know that it posting back.   You may get AMPscript HTTPPost to work, but if not, this is still a viable solution.  Good luck!

Comment: Cool thanks, I'll try that. On another note - do you know of any way to test these POST requests?

Comment: Only by doing it live with my own email address.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be glamorous, but technically you can post to the web collect URL with all of the form fields as parameters and then parse the resulting HTML with JavaScript for a success condition.

```
https://cl.exct.net/subscribe.aspx?mid=###YOURMEMBERID###&lid=###YOURLISTID###&Email%20Address=####YOUREMAIL####&SubAction=sub_add_update
```

If you don't  specify the page parameters, you'll get redirected to default ET pages.